# Move OpenGL ES objects with accelerometer

Tags: android, opengl-es, accelerometer, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I'm developing an Android application. I want to do the following:

I will have a black screen with an object in its center, for example, a vase.

With this app, I will a 360 degrees view of vase. I explain: imagine the vase is the center of an imaginary circle. I want to make user follow this circle, to see the vase from any point of view. I don't know if I explain it well.

In real life, you can move around a vase and see it in front, behind, and other sides. I want to simulate this.

My problem is that I'm not sure if I can simulate this using accelerometer.

Who can I know if user is describing a circle with the mobile phone?

If you don't understand me or you need more details, please tell me.

Comment: So how did your do it?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine accelerometer with compass. Compass gives you direction.